# iOS Storyboards: Can you set button hight based on title size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, xcode6

Is there any  way to set button height based on the title.if i am not pass any title to  the button then it must be zero height ,if i pass title to button  height will be fit to title  size .How can i achieve this using Storyboards

Comment: @DipenChudasama Height not width

Comment: What exactly you want to do ?

Comment: @DipenChudasama i want change height depending on title text ,if i set title nil it's height must be zero,if set title it change height will be increase  depending on title text  size

Comment: Whats the width of button..by default ?

Comment: @DipenChudasama width will be change depending on device size using autolayouts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74389/discussion-between-muralikrishna-and-dipen-chudasama).